# VB.net Aforge video capture - Memory is consumed and freezes the Camera

Tags: vb.net, video-capture, vb.net-2010, aforge

I wrote code using Aforge to capture the Video from the camera and its working fine. My problem is when I just start the Camera in the preview mode only without recording the camera (preview window) freezes after 15 or 20 seconds. Then I noticed in the Task Manager that the cause is the process vhost32-clr.exe which starts to consume the memory until reaches +- 1,600 MB then the camera freezes.

Noting that I wrote another code using DirectShow capture instead of Aforge and its working with no issues where the process vhost32-clr.exe does not exceed 30 MB of memory.

Here is my code :
I call below Sub in the form load

```
Public Sub callCam()

       PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        fiF = New FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice)
        finalVideo = New VideoCaptureDevice(fiF(0).MonikerString)
        finalVideo.VideoResolution = finalVideo.VideoCapabilities(0)
        'finalVideo.ProvideSnapshots = True
        AddHandler finalVideo.NewFrame, New NewFrameEventHandler(AddressOf Scapture)
        finalVideo.Start()
       
    End Sub
```

Once the above code is executed, the mentioned `vhost32-clr.exe` starts to consume the memory then freezes the camera preview, without executing any other code.

below is the `Scapture sub`

```
 Private Sub Scapture(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal eventArgs As NewFrameEventArgs)


        If ButtonVIDEO.BackColor = Color.Black Then 'In case of Preview only (No recording)

            Try
                BMP = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap) 'Put the data in the bitmap
                PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap) 'present it in the Picture Box

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try


        Else ' In case of Recording
            Try
                BMP = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap) 'Put the data in the bitmap
                PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap) 'present it in the Picture Box
                VFwriter.WriteVideoFrame(BMP) 'Save in Memory

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? I'm sure its related to the code not to the Windows nor Memory, since its working fine with different library.

Comment: So basically, the app is generating hundreds or thousands of BMP files a minute, and keeping hold of all of them til eventually it runs out of memory.? It does seem like a problem that needs solving

Comment: @Caius Jard. Well, thanks for explaining the cause, I will be happy to hear your thoughts for solving it.

Comment: So you've implemented it once with this preferred library and that's what happens... and the exact (or near as) same code with another lib works out? That implies that it's AForge's fault rather than your code? Is there some misconfiguration of AForge?

Comment: @CaiusJard, I lowered the resolution from `finalVideo.VideoResolution = finalVideo.VideoCapabilities(0)` which is 1280x720 to `finalVideo.VideoResolution = finalVideo.VideoCapabilities(5)` which is 640x360 and the problem solved. but this is not the desired solution as the user may need to use higher resolution. I ran out of ideas, any advice?

Comment: There isn't a memory leak with the lower resolution? Are you able to create a simple test app using just aforge and no other things, that reproduces the problem? It's would be helpful both for us on sO but also for reporting problem to aforge if needed

Comment: @CaiusJard, Yes an app with only the provided code for capturing the video will reproduce the problem check this link for app with source code uses exactly the same code and it reproduce the problem [http://visualbasictutoriales.blogspot.com/2015/03/webcam-video-aforge-con-visual-basic.html]. It would be great if we can report it to Aforge, I checked their forum but it requires login, and there is no signup option. will you be able to assist reporting the issue? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Sorry [Here](http://visualbasictutoriales.blogspot.com/2015/03/webcam-video-aforge-con-visual-basic.html) is the link, the above one is broken.

Comment: You actually have to call .Dispose() on the image objects you cloned.